# what is the meaning of these data.table expressions?

Tags: r, vector, data.table

Could someone tell me what these two data.table expressions do?

```
dt[,R_Fuel:=c(0, diff(dt[, Fuel]))]

dt[R_Fuel < 0 | R_Fuel > 5, R_Fuel:=NA]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the `data.table` parlance/dialect.

- In `data.table`, assignments should be done inside of the `[` brackets, and instead of the typical R assignment operators `<-`/`=`, one needs to use `:=`. Your first line is equivalent to

  ```r
  dt$R_Fuel <- c(0, diff(dt$Fuel))
  ```

  However, even this is not "good" data.table code, the use of `dt[,Fuel]` is unnecessary, it should be just

  ```r
  dt[, R_Fuel := c(0, diff(Fuel))]
  ```
- If you're curious about what the R code itself is doing, `diff(.)` returns the differences between values of a vector. Because it is the diffs, if done on a vector of length `n`, the return value is length `n - 1`. Since `data.frame`s (and `data.table`s) require that all columns have the same number of elements, the diffs need to have one value padded; in this case, pre-padded with `0`.
- Similar to base-R, when using `[i,j]`-notation, the `i` is a row-selector. Unlike base R, though, when `j` includes an assignment (as both of your expressions do), then the `i`-component does not subset the data in the return, it just changes which rows get the calculation. The second expression is similar to any of the following (R-basic and data.table-canonical versions, generally equivalent):

  ```r
  ## basic R
  dt$$R_Fuel <- ifelse(dt$R_Fuel < 0 | dt$R_Fuel > 5, NA, dt$R_Fuel)
  ## canonical data.table
  dt[, R_Fuel := ifelse(R_Fuel < 0 | R_Fuel > 5, NA, R_Fuel)]
  ## canonical data.table using the preferred `fifelse`
  dt[, R_Fuel := fifelse(R_Fuel < 0 | R_Fuel > 5, NA_real_, R_Fuel)]
  ```

  FYI, it might be more readable to use `between` here:

  ```r
  dt[ !between(R_Fuel, 0, 5), R_Fuel := NA ]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The first expression creates a new column (`R_Fuel`) in the data.table `dt`, which holds the row-over-row change (see `?diff`) in the values of `Fuel` in `dt`. Since there is no value for the first row, 0 is appended to the set of differences.  It would be better to write `dt[,R_Fuel:=c(0,diff(Fuel))]`

The second line, then replaces the new column `R_Fuel` to `NA` in all rows where `R_Fuel` is less than 0 or greater than 5